# Задача с двумерными массивами С++

Tags: c++, массивы

В общем ребят, есть задача с двумерными массивами. Условие : расставить на шахматном поле 2 белых и 2 черных слона произвольным образом и определить, какие черные слоны находятся под ударом белых.
Мой говно-код для одного белого слона ( для начала хотя бы с ним разобраться, затем копирнуть для второго ) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int n = 8;
    int a[n][n];
    int y[4], x[4];
    cout << "Here we go, there is chess desk, 0 - white figures, 1 - black figures, 6 - white elephant, 9 - black elephant\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {


        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 2;
            cout << a[i][j];
            cout << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        y[i] = rand() % 8;
        x[i] = rand() % 8;
        cout << "X IS" << "\t\t" << "Y IS" << "\t" << "Count from zero!!!" << endl;
        cout << y[i] << "\t\t" << x[i] << endl;
    }
    a[x[0]][y[0]] = 6;
    a[x[1]][y[1]] = 6;
    a[x[2]][y[2]] = 9;
    a[x[3]][y[3]] = 9;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {


        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j];
            cout << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i--) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j--) {

            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;
            }
            if (j--)
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i++) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j++) {

            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;
            }
            if (j++)
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i++) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j--) {

            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;

            }
            if (j--)
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = x[0]; i < n && i >= 0; i--) {

        for (int j = y[0]; j < n && j >= 0; j++) {

            if (a[i][j] == 9) {
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way" << endl;

            }
            if (j++)
                break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

После долгих раздумий что же не так я накоец осознал, что скорее всего проблема в этом :

```
if (j++)
    break;
```

Координата по y смещается 1 раз и застывает. Нужно придумать так, чтобы каждый цикл выполнялся по одному разу пока удовлетворяет условию. То есть производил проверку по диагонали. Нет идей, как это реализовать.

Comment: Если у вас есть черный слон в клетке `(b0,b1)` и белый в `(w0,w1)` - то белый его бьет, если `b0-w0 == b1-w1` или `b0-w0 == w1-b1`.

Comment: @Harry, один черный слон может заслонить другого.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал в одном цикле, примерно так (правда, для одного слона, но идея понятна). Посмотрите, может, подойдет что-то:

```
    int desk[8][8]; // доска (левый нижний угол = [1;1])
    int x = 2, y = 5;   // координаты белого слона

    // Далее координаты клеток, которые надо проверять, 
    // начальные значение равны координатам слона
    int ax = x, ay = y;     // по диагонали вниз-влево
    int bx = x, by = y;     // по диагонали вверх-влево
    int cx = x, cy = y;     // вниз-вправо
    int dx = x, dy = y;     // вверх-вправо

    desk[4][7] = 9;     // Для проверки разместил черного слона

    cout << "START" << endl;

    // Теперь идем по всем направлениям, пока не дойдем до краев
    // Или пока не найдется вражеский слон.
    do {
        if (ax > 1 && ay > 1) {
            ax--; ay--;
            if (desk[ax][ay] == 9) { 
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way: x=" << ax << ", y=" << ay << endl;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if (bx > 1 && by < 8) {
            bx--; by++;
            if (desk[bx][by] == 9) { 
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way: x=" << bx << ", y=" << by << endl;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if (cx < 8 && cy > 1) {
            cx++; cy--;
            if (desk[cx][cy] == 9) { 
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way: x=" << cx << ", y=" << cy << endl;
                break; 
            }
        }
        if (dx < 8 && dy < 8) {
            dx++; dy++;
            if (desk[dx][dy] == 9) { 
                cout << "One black elephant is on the way: x=" << dx << ", y=" << dy << endl;
                break;  
            }
        }
    } while ((ax > 1 && ay > 1) || (bx > 1 && by < 8) || (cx < 8 && cy > 1) || (dx < 8 && dy < 8));

    cout << "END" << endl;
```